# is it possible to create name of table in @Database annotitation?

Tags: android, android-room

i want to create two table with one model.how can i do that?

this is my model

```
@Entity(tableName = "user_table")
class UserModel
    : Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    var _id: String = ""

    var userName: String? = null

    var userAvatar: String? = null

    @TypeConverters(ConvertersDAO::class)
    var birthDate: Date? = null

    var gender: String? = null

}
```

and my database

```
@Database(entities = [UserModel::class], version = 1,exportSchema = false)
abstract class UserRoomDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getUserDao() : UserDAO

    companion object{
        @Volatile
        private var instance : UserRoomDatabase?= null
        fun getInstance(context : Context): UserRoomDatabase{
            if(instance==null)
                instance = Room
                    .databaseBuilder(context,UserRoomDatabase::class.java,"UserRoomDatabase")
                    .build()
            return instance!!
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

> i want to create two table with one model.how can i do that?

In short you cannot as it is the `@Entity` annotation and the inclusion of the class as an Entity in the @Database class which defines the Class as **a** table.

The closest that you would get to using a Class as a model would be to either a) inherit the UserModel class or b) embed the UserModel class into another class using `@Embedded`.

However, you would still need either separate Dao's, *as the table name is specified within and cannot be a variable*, or use raw queries that are not checked at compile time, where the table name could be passed as a variable.

It would probably be far simpler, to have a single table with a column, possibly indexed, that indicates the group (User) to which a row belongs.

Comment: oh i understood. thanks so much